# Entity framework with MySQL

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

hello i installed MySQL Connector/Net 6.7.4 so i was able to generate edmx from my MySql database, but now i wanna do smth with it so i added connetion string and :

```
    <DbProviderFactories>
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
</DbProviderFactories>
```

in my webconfig, but when i create context(pure generated by .tt) i got an exception on collection:

The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid.

Any ideas why? I already added MySql.xxx dlls to my bin

Edit: connstring was wrong when i modified provider name so it looks now:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="classicmodelsEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/mysql.Model1.csdl|res://*/mysql.Model1.ssdl|res://*/mysql.Model1.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=Password;persist security info=True;database=classicmodels&quot;" providerName="MySQL Data Provider"/>
```

i got exception :Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

Comment: Whats you connection string?

Comment: adding <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> did not help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Entity Framework, why are you adding a connection string? The connection string generated for me was different:

```
<add name="stuffEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.MyModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.MyModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.MyModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=myserver.com;user id=my_user;password=my_password;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=db_example&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Add your MySQL references on References, with True for Local copy. Also add the required configuration in Web.config, installing through **NuGet** the missing package.

To do this, right click your solution or project, click on Manage NuGet packages, and install the missing MySQL.Data reference. This should modify your Web.config with the reference.